# python psycopg2

Tags: python, sql

Не могу понять как написать функцию или цикл, которая бы из списка разных БД подставляла в запрос разные названия схем.
Вот пример, что я хотел бы получить.
Подскажите, есть ли какая то специальная функция для этого.

```
def func(data):
    cursor.execute('select * from data.sessions')
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    records
```

Comment: Что хотите получить?

Comment: Да хоть f-строки: `cursor.execute(f'select * from {data}.sessions')`

Comment: Хочу получить данные, а потом их объединить из разных схем, по смыслу как оператор UNION, только в python